# Helm: render variable in a block inserted with toYaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a variable block configuring triggers in a Keda scaled object like so:

```yaml
# [...] 
    autoscaling: 
      enabled: true
      triggers:
      - type: prometheus
        metadata:
          serverAddress: http://prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
          metricName: prometheus_redis_message_count
          query: avg(redis_queue_job_states_total{state=~"waiting|active", namespace="{{ $.Release.Namespace }}", queue="reports"}) without (instance, pod, pod_template_hash, state) 
          threshold: '1'
          activationThreshold: '1'
# [...]
```

as you can see, *autoscaling.triggers[0].metadata.query* contains a variable ( .Release.Namespace ) which does not get rendered when using the toYaml function (which is understood).
Is there a way, maybe with some named template magic or so, to put all items in *triggers* into my rendered template while also rendering vars contained inside (like .Release.Namespace?)

Right now I have it like this (which does work for now so I can proceed), but obviously is not great because it's way to static (won't allow multiple triggers or even other trigger types in the future):

```yaml
# [...]
    - type: prometheus
        metadata:
          serverAddress: http://prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
          metricName: prometheus_redis_message_count
          {{- with index .autoscaling.triggers 0 }}
          query: {{ tpl .metadata.query $ }}
          {{- end }}
          threshold: '1'
          activationThreshold: '1'
# [...]
```

edit:
thanks to David's reply I was able to write it like so:

```yaml
  triggers:
{{- range .autoscaling.triggers }}
  - type: {{ .type }}
    metadata:
      query: {{ tpl .metadata.query $ }}
      serverAddress: {{ tpl .metadata.serverAddress $ }}
      threshold: {{ tpl .metadata.threshold $ | quote }}
      activationThreshold: {{ tpl .metadata.activationThreshold $ | quote}}
      metricName: {{ tpl .metadata.metricName $ }}
{{- end }}
```

which makes it a valid array and also templates all the fields. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty answer is to just run `tpl` on the output of `toYaml`.  `toYaml` takes an arbitrary structure and returns a string, but at that point it's just a string and there's nothing particularly special about it.

```yaml
triggers:
{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.autoscaling.triggers) . | indent 2 }}
```

I'm not clear that anything more nuanced is possible without iterating through the entire list and running `tpl` on each individual structure.

```yaml
triggers:
{{- range .Values.autoscaling.triggers }}
  - type: {{ .type }}
    metadata:
      query: {{ tpl .metadata.query $ }}
{{- end }}
```

Neither the core Go templating language nor the Sprig extensions have any sort of generic "map" function that could operate on the values of a nested object while retaining its structure.

Comment: wait that works? I had something like this in mind just was not able to put it into writing. Great, thanks!